# join tables without common column but related with range formula

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I want to join two tables
Table 1 has 4 columns-

```
ID   Name  Start_Date    End_date
1    John  20/dec/0009   15/Sep/0010
```

Table 2 has 3 columns-

```
Low High Frequency
1   50   Weekly
51  150  Monthly
```

Here, I have to report frequency based on the Low and High range which is End_date-start_date. How do I join these two?
Can't figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `1` low and `50` high were days difference between two dates?

Comment: Also **TAG** the `DBMS` you are using since the query requires `DATE` functions which differs with each vendor

Comment: "Is 1 low and 50 high were days difference between two dates?" YES and it's Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.Name, Table2.Frequency 
FROM Table1 
  JOIN Table2 ON 
    Table2.Low >= DateDiff(d, Table1.End_Date, Table1.Start_Date) AND 
    Table2.High < DateDiff(d, Table1.End_Date, Table1.Start_Date)
```

Comment: The DATEDIFF function is specific to SQL Server.  I'm sure you just need to find the Oracle equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (ID, Name, Start_Date, End_date ) AS
SELECT 1, 'John', DATE '0009-12-20', DATE '0010-09-15' FROM DUAL; 

CREATE TABLE Table2 ( Low, High, Frequency ) AS
SELECT  1,   50, 'Weekly'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  51, 150, 'Monthly' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 151, 730, 'Yearly'  FROM DUAL ;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t1
       INNER JOIN
       table2 t2
       ON ( end_date - start_date BETWEEN LOW AND HIGH );
```

**Output**:

```
        ID NAME START_DATE          END_DATE                   LOW       HIGH FREQUENCY
---------- ---- ------------------- ------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------
         1 John 0009-12-20 00:00:00 0010-09-15 00:00:00        151        730 Yearly
```